# Terminal outputs LogLeveling for process run through extensionHostProcess.js

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This is more of a information based question as I cant seem to find resources regarding it.

I'm trying to look into setting logLevels for VSC: `extensionHostProcess.js`

When I run Build on some Extensions I have that compile small angular components.
The HostProcess Creates logs such as this:

[Logs Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSnAj.png)

Now I know in general this is console.warn/error/info logs however they are being processed by the HostProcess I know this from some callStacks and that I saw the exact logs creating these.

However it is a problem for me to have what I would consider Positive Logs such as:

`[2023-05-05T13:17:43.141] ERROR ✔ Copying assets`

Under a `console.error`

So my **Qeustions** is **How do I set the Loglevel of the extensionHostProcess.js?**

Comment: you can create a feature request at the VSC repo

Comment: if you do [create a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md), please add a link here to it for posterity.